# Alt+<something> app shortcuts don't work

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys

With Ubuntu 18.04, using Gnome, any *application* keyboard shortcut that contains <kbd>Alt</kbd> doesn't work. It behaves like if <kbd>Alt</kbd> wasn't pressed at all. So, for instance, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> does the action of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>.

For the system actions, the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key works: Alt-tab to switch windows for instance, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Also, activating menu items works - <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> rolls out the File menu, but any shortcut in it which contains <kbd>Alt</kbd> doesn't work.

So I think it's the system somehow aggressively catching the events and filtering out the information about Alt being pressed.

I checked that Window movement key is Super.
I have no further idea where should I look.
I am not aware of anything special installed regarding keyboard events processing.

What should I try?

Comment: Does Ctrl alt T open the terminal?

Comment: Yes, that works.